# Bootstrap menu fully shows when viewing in mobile.

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

Many thanks in advance! I am a graphic designer working with a SIMA bootstrapped template. I was unsuccessful at contacting the author of the template. All is kosher except for when you view the site on mobile, the navigation menu is fully displayed. The user has to manually click the nav tab to hide the menu (poor usability). I have searched similar questions and found that I have the correct Meta View tags and my navigation classes and id's seem to be all there. The link to my site is at [www.thesunkenweb.com/loteksystems](http://www.thesunkenweb.com/loteksystems) The link to the authors site (which has the same outcome) is https://readytheme.net/item/sima-one-page-multipage-template/
HTML Snippet:

```
    <!-- Start Header Section -->
    <header class="main_menu_sec navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="lft_hd">
                        <a href="index.html"><img src="http://www.thesunkenweb.com/loteksystems/img/LotekSystemsLogo_1.png" alt="Lotek Systems"/></a>
                </div>
            </div>          
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                <div class="rgt_hd">                    
                    <div class="main_menu">
                        <nav id="nav_menu">
                            <button aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#navbar" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>   
                        <div id="navbar">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
                                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#abt_sec">About Us<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#tm_sec">Meet Andy</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#tstm_sec">Testimonials</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#clt_sec">Experience</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>                       
                                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#pr_sec">Services<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="CustomCloudManagement.html">Custom Managed Cloud Hosting</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="CloudMigration.html">Cloud Migration</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="ApplicationManagement.html">Application Management</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="ComputerRepairs.html">Computer Repairs</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#ctn_sec">Contact Us</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>      
                        </nav>          
                    </div>                          
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>  
    </div>  
</header>
<!-- End Header Section -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media (max-width:767px){
  #navbar{display:none}
}
```

Add this and all would be kosher ☺

Comment: Thank you very much!! That makes so much sense. Thanks for helping us designers out! Cheers! – Don

Comment: Tried to give you a one up, but since I am brand new to Stack, i am not credited with giving one ups yet. I will soon enough!